# Setting the background drawable for Android button does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-styles

I have a created a shape in the file `greenRectangle.xml` is as follows:

```
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/white" />
  <solid android:color="@color/dgreen"/>
  <corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
 android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Here is the color.xml:

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
      <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
      <color name="lgreen">#558B2F</color>
      <color name="dgreen">#33691E</color>
      <color name="ddgreen">#33791E</color>
      <color name="black">#000000</color>
    </resources>
```

I tried to use the `greenRectangle` as background for a button but that does not work and the button becomes white!

Here is the button element:

```
<Button
        android:text="ورود"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        style="@style/AnatoliButton.Green"
        android:background="@drawable/greenrectangle" />
```

Why does this button not take effect?

Comment: are you sure `greenRectangle.xml` is same as `greenrectangle` check for file name capital - R

Comment: remove style from button

Comment: It works fine without the style attribute. Please check the style you used or share the same

Comment: Thanks for all comments there were two problems with the code. First of all I renamed greenRectangle.xml to greenrectangle.xml and then I set the background attribute in the style and it worked.

Comment: if you are defining style at background then why you are using style= tag ?

Comment: @sud I wanted to override the background property of style.